# Loop through form inputs and store data in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to create a javascript object.

```
const data = {};

// loop through each input found in form
$('#form_name').filter(':input').each(function() {
  const $id = $(this).attr('id');
  const $value = $(this).attr('value');
  data[$id] = $value;
  return data;
});
```

Checkout this fiddle to show you what I mean... https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5230/

Expected output would be something like this:

```
{
    "username": "johndoe",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    ...
}
```

This way currently does not work... How can I make this into a js object or if someone could offer a better way of doing this, that would be great. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: does it work? whats react keeping track of? can you post more code? hard to tell with just this...

Comment: @JordanHendrix i'll re-phrase the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: I removed the React parts of your question - it's unrelated to your issue

Comment: You may like to use an array of object like this example https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/136/

Comment: @MatthewHerbst hey thanks! i also made some edits to maybe give people a better idea on whats going on

Comment: @Matt.k i kinda need it as a js object. but thanks for posting a suggestion :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not return data object in the each loop, but after:

```
var setData = function(){
   var data = {};

   $('#form_name').filter(':input').each(function() {
       const $id = $(this).attr('id');
       const $value = $(this).attr('value');
       data[$id] = $value;
   });

   return data;
}

var data = setObject();
```

also, you should not define your object as a constant since you change its value right after

Answer (score 2):

Non-jQuery version:

```
var formElements = document.getElementById('form_name').childNodes;
var obj = {};
for(element in formElements) {
  if(formElements[element].nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    obj[formElements[element].id] = formElements[element].value
  }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d5uejqLf/